# Error "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties : UseMySql" in asp.net core

Tags: c#

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder,
> string,
> System.Action<MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder>)'
> and
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder,
> string,
> System.Action<MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder>)'

My code is

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<ProjectDataContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 different using statements that have the same method. Are you sure you have only one NuGet package for that?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you might find the Pomelo MySQL package is 100x better than the MySql.Data one - something to keep in mind if you see random problems/slowness

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The [Microsoft EntityFramework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) actually directly links to [Pomelo MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)!

Comment: As Camilo Terevinto says, you seemto have a Nuget problem.
(1) look for a difference in the two function prototypes in the error message.
(2) Google the difference you have found, namely MySql.EntityFrameworkCore and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. 
(3) Remove the spurious nuget package.

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto, thanks, Pomelo MySQL works for me

Answer (score 0):

From the error is is clear that you are referencing thes two packages in the `using` section:

```
using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder;
```

To resolve this, either remove the one you don't want to use, or (if both are needed in your class) call the intended method directly and not as an extension one. For example:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ProjectDataContext>(options =>
    MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder.UseMySQL(options, _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

//or

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ProjectDataContext>(options =>
    MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder.UseMySQL(options, _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```